# how to change keyboard layout in android by pressing Shift key

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method

I'm currently working on own implementation of `Input Method Editor (IME)` or can be called as `Softkeyboard` in Android, I have read [creating an input method](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/creating-input-method.html) and I have downloaded `the SoftKeyboard sample code provided as part of the SDK`. I have the following code from [sample Softkeyboard](https://gitorious.org/replicant/development/source/7b53e3937797ee1eea71c6291bdcd58cb9dedf7a:samples/SoftKeyboard/src/com/example/android/softkeyboard/SoftKeyboard.java#L550):

```
private void handleCharacter(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
    if (isInputViewShown()) {
        if (mInputView.isShifted()) {
            primaryCode = Character.toUpperCase(primaryCode);
        }
    }
    if (isAlphabet(primaryCode) && mPredictionOn) {
        /**
         * Swapping here with my desired unicode character
         * */
        if (primaryCode >= 97 && primaryCode <= 122 ) {
            mComposing.append(Swap.swapLetters(primaryCode));
        }else{
            mComposing.append((char) primaryCode);
        }
        getCurrentInputConnection().setComposingText(mComposing, 1);
        updateShiftKeyState(getCurrentInputEditorInfo());
        updateCandidates();
    } else {
        getCurrentInputConnection().commitText(
                String.valueOf((char) primaryCode), 1);
    }
}
```

the code given above works fine, but when I click the key:

```
<Key android:codes="-1" 
            android:keyWidth="15%p" android:isModifier="true"
            android:isSticky="true" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
```

which is like `Shift` key, this converts the keys to uppercase I don't know how to show my next keys this key is clicked/pressed, the following is `Logcat` of exception:

[image: Logcat of exception]

I have traced that this might be occurring in this place where we handle the `Shift` key :

```
private void handleShift() {
    if (mInputView == null) {
        return;
    }

    Keyboard currentKeyboard = mInputView.getKeyboard();
    if (mQwertyKeyboard == currentKeyboard) {
        // Alphabet keyboard
        checkToggleCapsLock();          
        mInputView.setKeyboard(mSindhi);            
    } else if (currentKeyboard == mSymbolsKeyboard) {
        mSymbolsKeyboard.setShifted(true);
        mInputView.setKeyboard(mSymbolsShiftedKeyboard);
        mSymbolsShiftedKeyboard.setShifted(true);
    } else if (currentKeyboard == mSymbolsShiftedKeyboard) {
        mSymbolsShiftedKeyboard.setShifted(false);
        mInputView.setKeyboard(mSymbolsKeyboard);
        mSymbolsKeyboard.setShifted(false);
    }
}
```

now I have not any idea how to get rid of exception mentioned above, and get my code working. please solve this one!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be some other solutions for your problem, but I have done one trick and came up with following :

**Step-1** You have to remove all the calls to the method `updateShiftKeyState(getCurrentInputEditorInfo());` in your code like:

```
private void handleCharacter(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
if (isInputViewShown()) {
    if (mInputView.isShifted()) {
        primaryCode = Character.toUpperCase(primaryCode);
    }
}
if (isAlphabet(primaryCode) && mPredictionOn) {
    /**
     * Swapping here with my desired unicode character
     * */
    if (primaryCode >= 97 && primaryCode <= 122 ) {
        mComposing.append(Swap.swapLetters(primaryCode));
    }else{
        mComposing.append((char) primaryCode);
    }
    getCurrentInputConnection().setComposingText(mComposing, 1);
    //updateShiftKeyState(getCurrentInputEditorInfo()); // you can delete this method from your class and clean-up all the occurances of that 
    updateCandidates();
} else {
    getCurrentInputConnection().commitText(
            String.valueOf((char) primaryCode), 1);
}}
```

**Step-2** change your `handleShift` method to his:

```
private void handleShift() {
    if (mInputView == null) {
        return;
    }

    Keyboard currentKeyboard = mInputView.getKeyboard();
    if (mQwertyKeyboard == currentKeyboard) {           
        mInputView.setKeyboard(mSindhi);

    } else if (currentKeyboard == mSymbolsKeyboard) {
        mInputView.setKeyboard(mSymbolsShiftedKeyboard);
    } else if (currentKeyboard == mSymbolsShiftedKeyboard) {
        mInputView.setKeyboard(mSymbolsKeyboard);
    }
}
```

that is all, Hope this may work for you...